# Modifying a non-static object from a static method

Tags: forms, static, methods, non-static

I'll first tell you what I am trying to do, and then how I am trying to do it.  If there is a better way please let me know.

I am working with two forms - lets call them form_main and form_preferences

When the form_preferences form is up, I want form_main to be disabled until a button (save button) on the form_preferences is clicked.

So here is what I am doing:
Button is clicked in form_main

```
form_preferences frm_p = new form_preferences();
frm_p.Visible = true;
this.enabled = false;
```

//so far so good

When I hit save on form_preferences it calls a public static method in form_main which needs to enable the form again.  Unfortunately I cannot do this directly because it is a static method.

I tried creating a new instance of the form, but then I would have to create the new instance and destroy the original one which seems like a big waste and inefficient.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand why did you created a static method, rather than an instance one to call?

Answer (score 1):

Change the form_main method to an instance method instead of static. Pass the instance of form_main to your sub_form when you create it, so it keeps a reference.

Comment: I tried this, but the frm_main.Enabled = true doesn't do anything on the main_form that I passed when I created this second form.
    public partial class frmsettings : Form
    {
        Form frm_main;
        public frmsettings(Form frmparent)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            frm_main = frmparent;
            
        }
      private void cmdsave_settings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
                frm_main.Enabled = true;
                this.Close();
                
        }

Comment: Didn't know that doesn't keep formats.

Basically in my public class, I have a public sub_form(Form frmparent){} which sets a global variable in the class equal to that that was passed in.  Later on when it is called it seems to have no effect on the parent form.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Okay so frm_main.Enabled = true; does not work, but frm_main.Close(); does for some reason....

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot, it works. I had a different object disabled instead of the form.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If there would be only one copy of your main form then make your form as singleton or use a static reference in your program to access it from within a static method.

In your main method do the following...

```
public static class Program {

  public static YourFrom form = null;

  public static void Main(string args[]) {
    Program.form = new YourFrom();
    Application.Run(form);   
  }
}
```

And whenever you need to access the form object in your class use the Program.form object to access it.